# React router v6 navigate() changes path, but not view

Tags: react-router

This is the logic what I'm building.

1. When user clicks `Delete` button, `onDelete` runs which dispatch thunk action.
2. After the item is deleted, navigate to '/home'

I added callback function which navigates page to home in `then()` of `dispatch` promise, but when I click delete button, it successfully deletes item, changes the URL, but not rendering the page of `/home`.

Can anybody give me some help?

Here's my code.

**App.tsx**

```ts
function App() {
  // ...

  // Router
  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      <>
        <Route
          index
          path="/"
          element={<RootPage />}
          errorElement={<ErrorPage />}
        />
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />

        <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
          <Route
            path="/profile/edit"
            element={<ProfileEditPage />}
            loader={profileLoader}
          />
          <Route path="/home" element={<HomePage />} loader={triplistLoader} />
          <Route path="/create" element={<TripEditPage />} />

          <Route element={<BottomNav />}>
            <Route path="/trip/:tripId" element={<MainPage />} />
          </Route>
        </Route>

        {/* Not Found Page */}
      </>
    ),
    { basename: process.env.PUBLIC_URL }
  );

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

**BannerTopNav.tsx (part of page /trip/:tripId)**

```ts
// ...

function BannerTopNav() {
  const authCtx = useAuthState();
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const [viewMenu, setViewMenu] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const dropDownRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const params = useParams();
  const tripId = params.tripId;

  const onDelete = () => {
    if (authCtx.state === "loaded" && authCtx.user && tripId) {
      dispatch(deleteTrip({ uid: authCtx.user.uid, id: tripId })).then(() => {
        navigate("/home", { replace: true });
      });
    }
  };

  // ...

  return (
    // ...
    {viewMenu && (
              <DropdownMenu
                menuArr={[
                  { label: "Delete", onClick: onDelete },
                ]}
              />}
            
}

export default BannerTopNav;
```

**store/TripReducer.ts**

```ts
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import TripAPI from "../utils/trip/apis";
import { PURGE } from "redux-persist";

export interface ITripData {
  title: string;
  user_id: string;
  image?: string;
  start_date: number;
  end_date: number;
  created_at: number; // timestamp
  updated_at: number; // timestamp
}

export interface ITrip {
  id: string;
  data: ITripData;
}

// [{id: ..., data: ...}, ...]
export interface ITriplist extends Array<ITrip> {}

export interface ITriplistState {
  status: "loading" | "loaded" | "error";
  state: ITriplist | undefined;
}

const initialState: ITriplistState = {
  status: "loading",
  state: undefined,
};

export const getTriplist = createAsyncThunk(
  "GET_TRIPLIST",
  async (uid: string, thunkAPI) => {
    return TripAPI.get(uid);
  }
);

export const addTrip = createAsyncThunk(
  "CREATE_TRIP",
  async (args: { uid: string; data: ITripData }, thunkAPI) => {
    return TripAPI.add(args.uid, args.data);
  }
);

export const updateTrip = createAsyncThunk(
  "UPDATE_TRIP",
  async (args: { uid: string; data: ITrip; id: string }, thunkAPI) => {
    // update
  }
);

export const deleteTrip = createAsyncThunk(
  "DELETE_TRIP",
  async (args: { uid: string; id: string }, thunkAPI) => {
    return TripAPI.delete(args.uid, args.id);
  }
);

export const triplistSlice = createSlice({
  name: "triplist",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getTriplist.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.status = "loaded";
      state.state = action.payload;
    });

    builder.addCase(addTrip.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      const { id, data } = action.payload;
      state.state?.push({ id, data });
    });

    builder.addCase(deleteTrip.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      const deleted_id = action.payload;
      state.state = state.state?.filter((trip) => trip.id !== deleted_id);
    });

    builder.addCase(PURGE, () => initialState);
  },
});
```

**store/index.ts**

```ts
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { profileSlice } from "./profileReducer";
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import { triplistSlice } from "./triplistReducer";

// 리듀서 설정
const reducers = combineReducers({
  profileReducer: profileSlice.reducer,
  triplistReducer: triplistSlice.reducer,
});

// redux-persist를 통한 상태 로컬 저장 설정
const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage, // 로컬스토리지에 저장
  // whitelist: 지정된 reducer를 저장
  // blacklist: 지정된 reducer를 저장에서 제외
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

// redux store 설정
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

I tried adding `replace: true` option to navigate, using `async await` instead of `then()`, using relative path such as `../../home`, but nothing worked fine.

I found when I delete the `dispatch(deleteTrip())` code, `navigate('/home')` works well. Seems dispatching an action makes problem to navigate..

Comment: Where is `BannerTopNav` being rendered? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve]? Can you also clarify what exactly you mean by "changes path, but not url"? The URL path ***is*** what should change when navigating.

Comment: @DrewReese `BannerTopNav` is being rendered in `MainPage`, which path is `/trip/:tripId`, and I meant navigate() changes the url path, but not view.

Comment: I don't see any overt issues in the code you've shared that would allow for successful navigation and unsuccessful component rendering. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: @DrewReese It's difficult to create a separate demo 'cause my project is quite big. But I found when I delete the dispatch code in `onDelete` method, navigating to home runs correctly (it changes url and renders `/home` page). I think dispatching redux thunk action matters somehow to `useNavigate`, so I added my `deleteTrip` action on my post

Comment: @DrewReese I just commented out `state.state = state.state?.filter((trip) => trip.id !== deleted_id)` code in `extraReducer`. This made navigating to home works successfully even I dispatch action before call `navigate(/home)`. But updating the triplist state after `TripAPI.delete` is essential for me, because I don't want to fetch triplist from server every time when users go to `/home`.

Comment: @DrewReese Bro I found it what was the problem! But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

After I struggled for debugging, I found what was the problem.

In **App.tsx**, I used `useAppDispatch()` to subscribe triplist state from Redux store. So when the item is deleted, the redux state is updated, then `App()` is re-rendered because triplist state is updated. This causes re-calling `createBrowerRouter()`, which means router is revalidated. Since router is revalidated, the page `<BannerTopNav />` is being rendered re-renders, making `navigate('/home)` not work correctly.

So I optimized the router using `useMemo()`, making not to be revalidated whenever triplist is updated! Then I solved the problem! It navigates to /home after waiting for delete action fulfilled.

```ts
import ...


function App() {
  const authCtx = useAuthState();
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const profile = useAppSelector((state) => state.profileReducer);
  const triplist = useAppSelector((state) => state.triplistReducer);


  // Router
  const router = useMemo(() => {
    return createBrowserRouter(
      createRoutesFromElements(
        <>
          <Route
            index
            path="/"
            element={<RootPage />}
            errorElement={<ErrorPage />}
          />
          <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />

          {/* PrivateRoutes를 적용할 Route끼리 모은다 */}
          <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
            <Route
              path="/profile/edit"
              element={<ProfileEditPage />}
              loader={profileLoader}
            />
            <Route
              path="/home"
              element={<HomePage />}
              loader={triplistLoader}
            />
            <Route path="/create" element={<TripEditPage />} />

            <Route element={<BottomNav />}>
              <Route path="/trip/:tripId" element={<MainPage />} />
            </Route>
          </Route>

          {/* Not Found Page */}
        </>
      ),
      { basename: process.env.PUBLIC_URL }
    );
  }, [profileLoader, triplistLoader]);

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Yeah, that'll do it. You could/should move the `router` declaration out of the `App` component if you can, so it's provided as a stable reference.